# Injecting a function into a computation expression

Tags: dependency-injection, functional-programming, f#

The following code sample is from Scott Wlaschin's site [*F# for fun and profit*.](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/)

```
type LoggingBuilder() =
    let log p = printfn "expression is %A" p

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log x
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x

let logger = new LoggingBuilder()

let loggedWorkflow = 
    logger
        {
        let! x = 42
        let! y = 43
        let! z = x + y
        return z
        }
```

Is there a way to inject a function instead of `printfn` into the `LoggingBuilder()`?

Answer (score 6):

You can just add a parameter to the builder type:

```
type LoggingBuilder(lf: obj -> unit) =
    let log p = lf p

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log x
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x

let logger = new LoggingBuilder(printfn "expression is %A")
```

You could make the builder generic if you want to make the input type more specific than `obj` e.g.

```
type LoggingBuilder<'a>(lf: 'a -> unit) =
    ...

let logger = new LoggingBuilder<int>(printfn "Got %i")
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a short follow up question: can computation expression be composed without classes, i.e. can `LoggingBuilder` be a type that isn't a class?

Comment: @lejon - I'm not sure what you mean, do you want to make your builder a struct?

Comment: No, but something like `let logger = LoggingBuilder logFn` seems more.. fp-ish.

Comment: You can actually call a constructor exactly like this, so no need to change the type definition. But if you want you can also do `type LoggingBuilder<'a> = | LoggingBuilder of 'a -> unit`, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to replace `printfn` with a logger such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), you can use `Printf.ksprintf`.

```
open NLog
open NLog.Config
open NLog.Targets

let private logger =
    let config = new LoggingConfiguration()
    let consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget()
    config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget)
    consoleTarget.Layout <- Layouts.SimpleLayout.FromString
        @"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"

    let rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget)
    config.LoggingRules.Add rule

    LogManager.Configuration <- config
    LogManager.GetLogger "MyLogger"

type LoggingBuilder(lf: string -> unit) =
    let log format =
        let doAfter (s: string) = lf s
        Printf.ksprintf doAfter format

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log "%A" x
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x

let logger = new LoggingBuilder(logger.Info)
```